# TikZ: Create bounding box in tikz picture of control system diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, bounding-box

I have completed writing a control system in TikZ. I now want to create two coloured "boxes" with dashed lines which should entail my controller and plant components of the entire control loop. Please refer to the figure at the end to see what I mean.

**How can I do this in TikZ? The boxes need to look exactly the way in the picture and also have a title as shown.**

Also: How can I add descriptions on the lines as shown in the picture?

Thank you!

My code is here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Um Grafiken (bspw. das Logo) einbinden zu können
\usepackage{pgf, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=blue!10, rectangle, 
minimum height=2em, minimum width=5em]
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={Triangle[],thick,black}]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [draw,thick,-{Triangle[]}]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{triangle} = [draw,fill=red!20,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3]

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm,scale=1.0]
        \node [input](input){};
        \node [sum, right of=input, node distance=2cm](sum1){};
        \node [block, fill=cyan!20, right of=sum1, node distance=3cm](fbcont){Feedback};
        \node [sum, right of=fbcont, node distance=2cm](sum2){};
        \node [block, fill=pink!20, right of=sum2, node distance=3cm](act){Actuator};
        \node [block, fill=orange!20, right of=act, node distance=3.5cm](plant){Plant};
        \node [block, fill=green!20, above of=fbcont](ffcont){Feed-forward};
        \node [block, fill=brown!20, below of=act](sens1){Sensor};
        \node [input, below of=sum1](interim){};
        \node [output, right of=plant](out1){};
        \node [output, below of=out1](out2){};


        \draw [arrow] (sum1)--node{$e(t)$}(fbcont);
        \draw [arrow] (fbcont)--(sum2);
        \draw [arrow] (sum2)--node{$u(t)$}(act);
        \draw [arrow] (act)--(plant);
        \draw [line] (plant)--(out1);
        \draw [arrow] (out1)|-(sens1);
        \draw [arrow] (sens1)-|node[pos=0.99]{$-$} node [near end]{$y_m(t)$} (sum1);
        \draw [line] (interim)-|(input);
        \draw [arrow] (input)--node{$r(t)$}(sum1);
        \draw [arrow] (input)|-(ffcont);
        \draw [arrow] (ffcont)-|(sum2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Control loop example diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a task for the fit library, which allows you to fit certain nodes. You can play with the `inner sep` to make the margins smaller or larger. Note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fit}

\tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=blue!10, rectangle, 
minimum height=2em, minimum width=5em},
sum/.style={draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm},
input/.style={coordinate},
output/.style={coordinate},
pinstyle/.style={pin edge={Triangle[],thick,black}},
arrow/.style={draw,thick,-{Triangle[]}},
line/.style={draw,thick,-},
triangle/.style={draw,fill=red!20,regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=2cm,scale=1.0]
        \node [input](input){};
        \node [sum, right of=input, node distance=2cm](sum1){};
        \node [block, fill=cyan!20, right of=sum1, node distance=3cm](fbcont){Feedback};
        \node [sum, right of=fbcont, node distance=2cm](sum2){};
        \node [block, fill=pink!20, right of=sum2, node distance=3cm](act){Actuator};
        \node [block, fill=orange!20, right of=act, node distance=3.5cm](plant){Plant};
        \node [block, fill=green!20, above of=fbcont](ffcont){Feed-forward};
        \node [block, fill=brown!20, below of=act](sens1){Sensor};
        \node [input, below of=sum1](interim){};
        \node [output, right of=plant](out1){};
        \node [output, below of=out1](out2){};

        \draw [arrow] (sum1)--node{$e(t)$}(fbcont);
        \draw [arrow] (fbcont)--(sum2);
        \draw [arrow] (sum2)--node{$u(t)$}(act);
        \draw [arrow] (act)--(plant);
        \draw [line] (plant)--(out1);
        \draw [arrow] (out1)|-(sens1);
        \draw [arrow] (sens1)-|node[pos=0.99]{$-$} node [near end]{$y_m(t)$} (sum1);
        \draw [line] (interim)-|(input);
        \draw [arrow] (input)--node{$r(t)$}(sum1);
        \draw [arrow] (input)|-(ffcont);
        \draw [arrow] (ffcont)-|(sum2);

        \node[fit=(sum1|-sens1)(ffcont)(sum2)(input),draw,blue,dashed,
        label={[blue]above:Controller}]{};
        \node[fit=(sens1)(plant),draw,orange,dashed,
        label={[orange]above:Controller}]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! It did what I wanted :)